# Tandberg Products (Accuvault RDX 1TB &4TB)

Tags: network-attached-storage, network-storage, removable-storage

http://www.span.com/product_info.php?products_id=33037

I am interested in getting the above to backup our existing NAS for off site storage.

Has anyone used these ? recommendations ? Alternatives ?

Is there anything available like a USB (2.5) Disk with a network port that I can backup my nas onto ?

or I was thinking to replace the existing NAS with the following : 
http://www.tandbergdata.com/us/index.cfm/products/tandberg-data-disk-based-data-protection-solutions-dps1000-dps2000/accuvault-series/dps3120/

as then it includes RDX for off site.

I have came across another NAS device by Actidata 
http://www.actidata.com/de/produkte/actinas-plus.html  (This one has the RDX installed within the Unit which makes it more desirable - but I can't seem to find any one who is selling this within the UK.

Will be grateful for your input on this

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AccuVault appliances from Tandberg Data are a great choice for predominantly Windows environments.  These systems all come pre-packaged with Windows Storage Server Basic, and AccuGuard Enterprise software.  The AccuGuard software does source-side depulication, which usually comes with hefty price tag - so this is great value given everything that's included. Your client computers are managed from a central console.  Some basic replication (synchronizing to RDX) is included.  The AccuGuard software is a relatively new product for Tandberg Data, but it is based on an Enterprise class data protection solution.  You'll likely be amazed at how well everything works together. The dedupe rate is excellent, but be aware you need to patient on the first backup as everything is indexed and deduped (this is usual for all dedupe software).  After that it runs very fast.  The RDX drive makes for excellent offsite storage, and the combination is cool!  Go with the 1U models if your working set of data is more than 1TB and hook up a standalone RDX dock. You can get RDX cartridges at 1TB capacity. The software allows you to rotate several cartridges (sort of like using tape rotation only a lot easier).

Comment: Thanks - I have inquired with different vendors too, and the Tandberg RDX only model is very expensive for our client. But it is very tempting as you can backup 1TB to a cartridge and take / ship it offsite. Would you know of a USB Backup Drive (which has a Network connection) too that I can install for this client and copy their central storage onto it ?